# Closest li without span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, closest

I'm trying to create a selector that will grab `li` element and show the text. The problem is that inside `li` tag I have `span` tag and that is also displayed.

How do I grab text of closest element without some of the elements inside?

see here, I don't want the word 'Edit' to be included.
http://jsfiddle.net/ozyf87tb/

```
<li>This is the story of the Jungle book
<form action="" method="" class="form_edit">
<textarea class="inte" value="" name="inte"></textarea>
</form>
<span class="edit">Edit</span>
</li>

$(".edit").click( function(ev) {
var a = $(this).closest('li').text();
$('.inte').val(a);
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ozyf87tb/7/

Clone it (so you work with the clone, not in the DOM), get children, remove the children, get the text.

```
$(".edit").click( function(ev) {

 var a = $(this).closest('li').clone().children().remove().end().text();

$('.inte').val(a);
});
```

Comment: I would love this one the best, why was it down-voted?

Answer (score 3):

The most readable way to do what you want to do is surrounding your text with a container like `<span class='myText'></span>`. So you could select the exact container using its class :
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ozyf87tb/2/)

```
<li><span class='myText'>This is the story of the Jungle book</span>
<form action="" method="" class="form_edit">
<textarea class="inte" value="" name="inte"></textarea>
</form>
<span class="edit">Edit</span>
</li>

$(".edit").click( function(ev) {
var a = $(this).prevAll('.myText').text();
$('.inte').val(a);
});
```

Comment: sorry I can't modify html

Answer (score 3):

First, get a [`clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) of the html.

```
var a = $(this).closest('li').clone();
```

Then remove the extraneous span.

```
a.find('span').remove();
```

Then put that into the textarea.

```
$('.inte').val( a.text() );
```

This can also be rewritten into a single string, but takes away from readability.

```
var a = $(this).closest('li').clone().find('span').remove().end().text();
$('.inte').val( a );
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/filoxo/ozyf87tb/3/)

Comment: why do you clone li first?

Comment: `.clone()` creates a copy of the DOM elements you've selected so that you can work with it without actually referring to the page elements. Otherwise, you would be removing the span that is shown on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Use `contents()` and then filter your selection to return only text nodes. Then all you need to do is to trim any white-space:

```
var a = $.trim($(this).closest('li').contents().filter(function(){
    return this.nodeType == 3;  
}).text());
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ozyf87tb/5/)

**Documentation**

- [`$.trim()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fjquery.trim%2F&ei=6MDsU-GHMoPD0QWi1YHIDQ&usg=AFQjCNEZ6fJOjhZdwoFCDBZnP_tGOFgcPw&sig2=TH-08Ohqv3xpfGrsQPTxqA&bvm=bv.72938740,d.d2k)
- [`.contents()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Fcontents%2F&ei=68DsU5jcKcWr0QWt1YCoAQ&usg=AFQjCNHEUP-SOzobglwGe3ZqGTJSJsJbKw&sig2=K3lF5070O2aVckLL5fCjBQ&bvm=bv.72938740,d.d2k)
- [`.filter()`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.jquery.com%2Ffilter%2F&ei=78DsU_3IA8jV0QWegYH4CQ&usg=AFQjCNGIjOndwopfFySn6E1gc8znkMPSPw&sig2=2_rKMS7ZexvulIIt7coEWg&bvm=bv.72938740,d.d2k)
- [`Node.nodeType`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)

Comment: Too static, you don't use the given classes

Comment: Explain 'Too static'? There is no need to use classes as the snippet of code I've provided would be in context.

Comment: what is that number 3?

Comment: It means the node is a text node. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType)

Comment: You hard coded "3", what if the position of nodes change ? That's why I said "too static"

Comment: @singe31 `nodeType` isn't the position of the node, it's the type of node, as the name suggests.

Comment: It doesn"t matter whether it's a position or a type. What if he encloses the text in a `<a>` or if anything changes ? You should use the class edit as you can reliably think this is a structure that will stay

Comment: Anyway, that's not what I would do, you won't get my upvote for that :p